# How do I display updated value of input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an input and I set its value with jQuery

```
$('#' + inputId).val(function() {
    alert("SETTING VAL TO "+ myValue);
    return myValue;
});
```

Low and behold this sets the value, as verified in the console. However the displayed value in the input text area does not change. How do I do that?

Comment: what is myValue? and what does inputId identify (what type of element)?

Comment: myValue is a string.  In the test case, it is "Bar" as in the counterpart to "Foo".  inputId identifies an input element.

Comment: that code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/8yxNK/1/

Comment: Sorry this is a non question, it turned out that there were 2 elements  with the same id, but the chrome inspector showed the value as correct on the element, without the window displaying the right value.  tricky and unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had two elements with the same id.  Weird thing is the chrome element inspector showed the correct value attribute for the input, but the text did not change, presumably for this reason.